# Permutations of 7 numbers less than 50

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many solutions does the equation $a + b + c + d + e + f + g ≤ 50$ have if each variable must be a 
non-negative integer?

I feel that the answer is $50 \choose 7$?

but that seems far too simple.. Am I missing something huge?

Comment: It's not $50\choose 7$. Consider the analogous problem where $a+b+c+d+e+f+g\le 7$. If your method were correct, the answer would be ${7\choose 7} = 1$, but it isn't; it's actually much larger. Just among the solutions where each variable is 0 or 1, there are 128 solutions. I suggest you look into the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: What is the connection between the title and the question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\binom{57}{7}$.

Take $57$ apples and pick $7$ of them out as borders. Then $50$ apples are left and the borders split them up in $8$ parts. $a$ stands for the number at the left side of the utmost left border, $b$ for the number between the utmost left border and its neighbour border, et cetera. Finally $g$ is the number between the most right border and its neighbour border. Together with the apples on the right side of the utmost right border they add up to $50$, so $a+\cdots+g\le50$.

Comment: Note that the question asks for sums that are at most 50, not sums that are equal to 50.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, I indeed overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a generating function. Each letter $a, ..., g$ has the same constraint. So we model an individual constraint:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{i} = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

Now we have seven elements, so we have our generating function $gen(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{7}}$. And so using our binomial identities, we get the coefficient of $x^{50}$ as $\binom{50 + 7 - 1}{50}$.

Edit: I missed that you want the count for less than or equal to 50. So you can add up the binomial coefficients then:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{50} \binom{i + 50 - 7}{i} $$